# UIControl that's similar to UIPopoverController on iPhone and iPod Touch

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I'm looking for something vaguely similar to [UIPopoverController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopovercontroller) to use on iPhone and iPod Touch. I want to use this object to simply display text in a sort of speech bubble (similar to basic speech bubbles in a comic strip).

I've considered making this myself. I'd start with a `UIView` subclass that has a `UILabel` as a subview. While this will probably work it's missing some crucial elements that I think are hard to get just right. There's text wrapping, adjusting the size of the view based on font size, text length, the max width and height of the view etc. There's also the triangle that sticks out like in other speech bubbles. So before I re-invent the wheel I want to see what exists.

**What are some alternatives to `UIPopoverController` that work on iPhone and iPod Touch?**

Answer (score 1):

I used FPPopoverController from [FPPopover](https://github.com/alvises/FPPopover) for this purpose. But it has not been updated for years.